# Select fields from joined tables with querydsl JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using JPAQueryFactory from QueryDSL to join two tables, and I'm looking at solutions to select specific fields from both tables.

Given two classes (getter/setters omitted):

```
public class TaskJob { 
    private String id;
    private Long taskId;
}

public class Task { 
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

The following base query (with taskjob = QTaskJob.taskJob and task = QTask.task)

```
new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
    .select(taskJob)
    .from(taskJob).innerJoin(task).on(taskJob.taskId.eq(task.id))
    .fetch();
```

returns fields only for the TaskJob instances

```
[ { "id": "080459be-e2e4-40d1-a6ea-192e1983b0b1", "taskId": 125 },
  { "id": "740d3df3-26ed-4e23-8c45-d0c3ebdd1426", "taskId": 126 } ]
```

How do I pick, for instance, both taskjob.id and task.description fields?

```
new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
    .select(taskJob.id, task.description)
    .from(taskJob).innerJoin(task).on(taskJob.taskId.eq(task.id))
    .fetch();
```

fails with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.querydsl.core.types.QTuple$TupleImpl..`

```
new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
    .select(Projections.map(taskJob.id, task.description))
    .from(taskJob).innerJoin(task).on(taskJob.taskId.eq(task.id))
    .fetch();
```

returns

```
[ { "task.description": "desc125",
    "taskJob.id": "080459be-e2e4-40d1-a6ea-192e1983b0b1" },
  { "task.description": "desc126",
    "taskJob.id": "740d3df3-26ed-4e23-8c45-d0c3ebdd1426" } ]
```

Finally, if I define a DTO class such as

```
public class DTO {

    // fields from TaskJob
    private String id;
    private Long taskId;

    // fields from TaskJob
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    ...
    
}
```

I can then use:

```
new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
    .select(Projections.map(DTO.class, taskJob.id, task.description))
    .from(taskJob).innerJoin(task).on(taskJob.taskId.eq(task.id))
    .fetch();
```

and get what I actually need:

```
[ { "description": "desc125",
    "id": "080459be-e2e4-40d1-a6ea-192e1983b0b1" },
  { "description": "desc126",
    "id": "740d3df3-26ed-4e23-8c45-d0c3ebdd1426" } ]
```

The DTO solution is fine by me, but is there a way to achieve the same result without a DTO class?